# is this proof about limits valid

Tags: limits

Is this proof valid? Can d be relative to x ?
[image]

Comment: You are close, but you need your definition of $\delta$ to not depend on $x.$  First insist that $\delta \le 1$ then $|x+3| \ge 5$

Comment: You can restrict $x$ to a certain range (say, from $2$ to $4$), and that will allow you to place a constraint on $\delta$ that doesn't depend on $x$.  (It will depend on $\varepsilon$, but not $x$.)

Comment: thanks guys that's what i thought :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $\delta$ cannot depend on $x$. What you need to do is use the "when $x$ is close" part. If $|x-3|<\delta$, then $3-\delta<x<3+\delta$. So if you don't allow $\delta$ to be big (you don't want that), then $x$ is bounded. So, for instance you can take 
$$
\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}7\right\}.
$$
where the $7$ comes from the need to bound $|x+3|$ (see below). 
Now, if $|x-3|<\delta$, then 
\begin{align}
|x^2-9|&=|x-3|\,|x+3|\leq\delta\,|x+3|\leq\delta\,(|x|+3)\leq\delta(3+\delta+3)\\ \ \\
&=\delta(6+\delta)\leq7\delta\leq\varepsilon.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a $\delta$ which is independent of $x$ and depends only on $\epsilon.$

Note that  $0<\delta<1 \implies 2<x<4$, thus $|x+3|<7$

Try $\delta = \epsilon/7.$